# Разница между impl Trait и Box<dyn Trait>

Tags: rust, traits

В чём заключается разница между `impl Trait` и `Box<dyn Trait>`? Являются ли они взаимозаменяемыми?

Скажем... есть такой код:

```rust
trait Animal {
    fn noise(&self);
}

struct Sheep;

impl Animal for Sheep {
    fn noise(&self) {
        println!("beeeeh");
    }
}

fn get_sheep_one() -> impl Animal{
    Sheep{}
}

fn get_sheep_two() -> Box<dyn Animal> {
    Box::new(Sheep{})
}

fn main() {
    get_sheep_one().noise();
    get_sheep_two().noise();
}
```

Неужели разница между первой и второй функциями заключается только в том, что во втором случае возвращается объект типа `Box`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в том, что точный тип возвращаемый `impl Animal` должен быть выведен на этапе компиляции т.е. `fn get_sheep_one() -> impl Animal` для данной реализации эквивалентна простому возврату `Sheep`.

Если добавить ещё один тип:

```
struct Cow;

impl Animal for Cow {
    fn noise(&self) -> &'static str {
        "moooooo!"
    }
}
```

То такая функция уже не будет работать:

```
fn get_animal_by_str_bad(s: &str) -> Result<impl Animal, String> {
   if s == "Cow" {
      Ok(Cow{})
    } else if s == "Sheep" {
      Ok(Sheep{})
    } else {
      Err("Unknown animal".to_string())
    }
}
```

И выдаст ошибку [[playground]](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b6b468f9c68a233006a5ffc6a49cfc7):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:25:10
   |
25 |       Ok(Sheep{})
   |          ^^^^^^^ expected struct `Cow`, found struct `Sheep`
   |
   = note: expected type `Cow`
              found type `Sheep`
```

Текст ошибки несколько запутан, но логика его такая: исходя из того, что первым возвращаемым значением по ходу текста было `Cow`, `rust` вывел, что `impl Animal` должно быть типа `Cow` и возмущается, когда после того, как он решил, что будет корова, ему подсовывают овцу.

Для того чтобы это преодолеть это ограничение, как раз и нужно использовать `Box` и `dyn` [[playground]](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f632285fbb19739feabb3e16df0e185):

```
fn get_animal_by_str(s: &str) -> Result<Box <dyn Animal>, String> {
   if s == "Cow" {
      Ok(Box::new(Cow{}))
    } else if s == "Sheep" {
      Ok(Box::new(Sheep{}))
    } else {
      Err("Unknown animal".to_string())
    }
}
```

По сути вся эта структура означает, что мы возвращать ссылку на динамический объект (`Box`), который реализует (об этом говорит `dyn`) поведение `Animal`.

---

В исходном варианте практической разницы в общем то нет, разве что вариант с `Box` будет иметь оверхед на выделение/освобождение памяти и разыменование ссылки. Но по сути это два разных действия.

Comment: В каких тогда случаях используется `impl MyTrait` в качестве результата? В случаях, когда тип возвращаемого функцией значения зависит от типа шаблонной функции, которая вызывается внутри?

Comment: В любых случаях, когда конкретный тип не важен для вызывающего кода и выводится из выражения, возвращающего значение.

Comment: @user263096, добавлю к тому что сказал mzabaluev — на практике обычно это бывает в дженериках.